# Centos 6.7 install PHP module for Apache

Tags: apache, php-5.6, mod-php

Im using a vagrant build vm and trying to install mod_php.

yum install mod_php
.....
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.6.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64
Error: httpd24u conflicts with httpd-2.2.15-47.el6.centos.1.x86_64
Error: httpd24u-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.15-47.el6.centos.1.x86_64

I guess hes trying to download the module for php 7? 
How can i install it for php 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

you're installing the wrong version of mod_php. try: yum install mod_php70u